# Swift UI IOS 15 ScrollView Adjustment

Tags: swift, swiftui, scrollview, ios15, swiftui-foreach

I don't know about you guys, but when I opened up my project today (the first time since Swift switched to running iOS 15 as the default) my UI looked shockingly different. Most importantly, previously adjacent views inside a ForEach now have some padding in between.

How can we eliminate this? I've included some sample code but I hope we can find a solution that can generalize. The actual problem in my UI has too many moving parts to include here.

```
struct IntItem: Identifiable {
    let num: Int
    let id = UUID()
  
}


struct ItemView: View {
    var item: IntItem
    
    var body: some View {
        Text(String(item.num))
            .padding(10)
            .border(Color.black)
          
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    let array: [IntItem]
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            ScrollViewReader { thing in
                ForEach(array) { item in
                    ItemView(item: item)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


let content = ContentView(array: [IntItem(num: 0), IntItem(num: 1), IntItem(num: 2), IntItem(num: 3)])
```

Comment: in `ItemView` you could try `.padding(.horizontal, 10)`

Comment: Wouldn't it be vertical? And I would prefer for the borders to touch without extra padding on the inside for aesthetic reasons.

Comment: in other words, you haven't try it.

Comment: ?? I tried it and it didn't change anything

Comment: tested on real devices, macos 12.beta, xcode 13.beta(not release), 
target ios 15 and macCatalyst 12.
What system are you using and targeting?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here's what worked--using a *vertical* padding of a negative number (in my case 4) on each individual view. I would still like clarification on why this changed with iOS 15.

Comment: I'm interested in your solution, could you edit your question with the code you used to "make it work".

Comment: just as I thought